# I need to use the exact version of Julia V1.0.0, where can I find it?

Tags: julia

I intend to use a package which requires Julia v1.0.0

I have used other versions like v0.7.0, v1.0.4 and later releases but non of them works with the package.

Comment: Is it a **true** requirement or you could just grab the package and update requirements to match say `0.7.0` (which should be identical to `1.0.0`) or `1.0.4` (which is a bug-fixing version of `1.0.0`)? Alternatively, you could grab `julia`'s git a recompile the exact version you need yourself.

Comment: It is not a true requirement but the package isn't working with those two packages. I don't understand what you mean by grabbing Julia's git.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer your question, but I'm curious.  Which package is it?  Maybe there is another package version or an easy fix for it to work with more versions of Julia.

Comment: The package is Laplacians#master which has a couple of functions for different purposes. There are two functions included to test if the package is working or not. With Julia v0.7.0 none of the works and with Julia v1.0.4 just one of them works. In the package documents, it is noted that the package works with Julia v1.0.0. So, I assume that I need to install the exact Julia version. Please let me know if I am wrong. https://github.com/danspielman/Laplacians.jl

Comment: I don't think it requires 1.0.0, but rather that it requires some Julia version > 1.0.0, so 1.0.4 should also work, if not it is a bug, either in the package or in Julia itself. I would open an issue (https://github.com/danspielman/Laplacians.jl/issues) and describe your problem there, including what code you are running and what the errors are.

Answer (score 2):

If the package you are after is not working with `1.0.4` there are solid chances that it will not work with `1.0.0` either, or that it is relying on an unintended feature, colloquially also known as *bug*.

However, to get binaries for different versions of Julia, you have a number of options.

## Option 1

Go to the [Download page of the Julia website](https://julialang.org/downloads/) and grad the version you need.

However, not all available downloads have a corresponding link.

In your specific case, you should pick up the binary corresponding to the architecture you are interested in, copy the link, modify the link to replace the version info, and finally use the link.

For example, starting from: https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/winnt/x64/1.0/julia-1.0.4-win64.exe

Replace `1.0.4` with `1.0.0`:
https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/winnt/x64/1.0/julia-1.0.0-win64.exe

(I am not sure how long this *trick* would work).

## Option 2

This is the safest method because it relies on the actual source history of the project (version control systems were made also for this).

You basically grab / check out the source:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/releases/tag/v1.0.0

And then you would compile it yourself.
Instructions on how to do that are available [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#building-julia).

Comment: I already downloaded that but I don't know how to install it (or compile it?). Probably cuz I'm very beginner with Julia.

Comment: You can also just download the binary from https://julialang.org/downloads/ . Just replace the version in the url with the version you want, e.g. at the time of writing change 1.0.4 to 1.0.0.

Comment: It seems incredibly unhelpful to suggest "download git, checkout a tag, and recompile" to a novice... Please do go for the julialang.org/downloads and just edit the url. However, as most other people have mentioned, it is much more probable that there is a bug with the package you want to use, not a real requirement for julia 1.0.0.

Comment: On the other hand it's the safest approach... if the 1.0.0 does not have a link in the download pages, it looks a little brittle to suggest, in general, link renaming as a method for obtaining versions of Julia not available in the official download page. Is the build guaranteed to last long-term where it is?

Comment: I downloaded version 1.0.4 and changed the name in url to 1.0.0 but when I install and run Julia, it still shows Julia v1.0.4 and the problem is not solved. I am using mac and already have v1.0.4 installed. I am not sure if I should uninstall v1.0.4 and then install v1.0.0 again.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is the correct answer even if you had problems with managing multiple versions on your computer. You should consider accepting it as an answer.